# how to open subfolder with fstream in c++

Tags: c++

hello I want to read a file located in a subfolder of my program.I succeeded to read the file in the mainfolder of my program.But i cant  read the file in a subfolder. 
I tried to add a  new string named subdir = "/*/" and do like this to get the subfolder but the program refused to take the new paths with my string subdir.Does anyone has a clue on how to do it ? I am running out of ideas lool.

```
char resulta[ MAX_PATH];
  DWORD flicksa = GetModuleFileName(NULL,resulta,MAX_PATH);
  _chdir(std::string(resulta,GetCurrentDirectory(flicksa,resulta)).c_str());
 std::string path = "/Users/Aymann/Desktop/arraysort/2CPP-REVISIONS/Supcount/";
std::string searchPattern = "/*.cpp";
std::string fullSearchPath = path + searchPattern;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
HANDLE hFind;

hFind = FindFirstFile( fullSearchPath.c_str(), &FindData ); 

if( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    cout << "Error searching directory\n";
    return -1;
}

do
{
    char c;
    string filePath = path + FindData.cFileName;
    ifstream in( filePath.c_str() );
    if( in.is_open() )
    {in.get(c);
       while (in) {
         while (in && c != '\n') {

           in.get(c);
         }
         _rowcount = _rowcount + 1;
         in.get(c);

       } // do stuff with the file here
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Problem opening file " << FindData.cFileName << "\n";
    }
}
while( FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData) > 0 );

if( GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES )
{
    cout << "Something went wrong during searching\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass wildcards to fstream.

Solution: descent folders, open files.

See glob(), opendir(), readdir(), closedir().